# quickest way to implement .net authentication in Web Forms with Entity Framework 6

Tags: webforms, asp.net-membership, entity-framework-6, claims-based-identity

I have been checking resources to implement authentication in my web forms application built with entity framework. All examples I found are MVC-related. I have used regular Asp.Net Membership framework a long time before I began to use EF. However, I could not find Membership implementation with Entity Framework code-first. I did implement the Claims-Based Identity (EF created the tables for me in DB) but I do not know how to utilize it in the application (like login), and it looks more complicated to me. Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of good tutorials on the asp.net web site:

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/membership-and-administration